# Getting parse error when trying to unit test John Papa style data service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, design-patterns

Currently I am using John Papa style data services as in example below and the problem with this approach is that I am getting "SyntaxError: Parse error" at 3rd line when trying to write a unit test for "getAvengers()" method:

**Service:**

```
function getAvengers() {
    return $http.get('/api/maa')
        .then(getAvengersComplete);

    function getAvengersComplete(response) {
        return response.data.results;
    }
}
```

**Unit test:**

```
describe("getAvengers", function() {
    var mockData = {
        data: {
            results: ["test 1", "test2"]
        }
    };

    it("", function(done) {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', "/api/maa").respond(200, mockData);
        dataservice.getAvengers()
            .then(function(data) {
                expect(data).toEqual(mockData.data.results);
                done();
            })
        $rootScope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

**Question**

Why I am getting parse error at this point? Unit test starts to work when I make these changes:

```
function getAvengers() {
    return $http.get('/api/maa')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data.results;
        });

    //function getAvengersComplete(response) {
    //    return response.data.results;
    //}
}
```